# How to update php openssl version?

Tags: php, openssl

I install openssl for windows and check version.
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0m9Ap.png

But My phpinfo show that
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/x9F51.png

I want php openssl version to upgrade version same installed openssl version.
Can I get some advice?

Comment: The ssl library used by php is typically independent from anything installed in your system. Instead php comes with its own modules, either in a modular setup as typical for Linux based systems where you could simply upgrade the php ssl module. For MS Windows one typically installs a php distribution found somewhere on the internet. So _most likely_ you will need to look for a php installer bundling the desired ssl library. Hard to be more specific without knowing your setup.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.